# Prove two Ideal are equal

Tags: ideals, finite-fields

Consider ideals of the ring $\frac{F[x]}{x^n-1}$ where $F$ is an arbitrary finite field.

Suppose $g(x) | (x^n-1)$ and $f(x) | (x^n-1)$ . Also suppose $A  = \left <g(x)\right>$ be the ideal that is generated by $g(x)$ and $B  =  \left<f(x)\right>$ be the ideal that is generated by $f(x)$ and $C =\left <g(x)\right> + \left<f(x)\right>$. Now find $h(x)$ such that $C= \left<h(x)\right>$.

hint = I think $h(x) = f(x) +g(x)+f(x)g(x)$ and I proved $\left<f(x) +g(x)+f(x)g(x)\right> \subseteq C$

Comment: Do you know what a greatest common denominator is, and how you would find it in a Euclidean ring (i.e. one in which you have well-behaved division with remainder)?

Comment: I know but how can I use it in my case?

Comment: Well, find a gcd of $f$ and $g$ (or lifts thereof) in $F[x]$, which is a Euclidean ring. Then take the residue of that in your ring.

Comment: Hmm. This wouldn't be about cyclic codes by any chance? :-) :-)

Comment: Whatever, I get a vibe that you are trying to mix two ways of looking at these ideals. Assuming that that the integer $n$ is coprime to the characteristic of the field, then each ideal can be generated either A) by a polynomial $g(x)$ that is a factor of $x^n-1$, or B) by a polynomial $e(x)$ that is *an idempotent*, in other words, $e(x)^2\equiv e(x)\pmod{x^n-1}$. The idempotent is uniquely determined by the ideal, the generator that is also a factor is unique up to a constant factor. **But, they are not equal in general.**

Comment: The reason I suspect this is that if $e_1(x)$ is the idempotent of the ideal $A$, $e_2(x)$ the idempotent of ideal $B$, then $e_1(x)+e_2(x)-e_1(x)e_2(x)$ is the idempotent of the ideal $A+B$. Should we be in characteristic two, then it makes no difference whether that sign is a plus or a minus... But at some point I will have exhausted my powers of divination. Anyway, what @Torsten said. You need the gcd to find a generator of the ideal that is also a factor of $x^n-1$.

Comment: Also observe that there will be plenty of generators! To any polynomial $g(x)$ let $d(x)=\gcd(g(x),x^n-1)$, then the ideals $\langle g(x)\rangle$ and $\langle d(x)\rangle$ are the same.

Comment: Not ruling out the possibility that I'm seeing coding theoretical structures even at places they were not intended to be present :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If $h(x) = gcd (f(x),g(x))$ and $c \in < f(x) > +< g(x) > $ we have $c \in < h(x) > $ because $$c= a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)$$ for some $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ and then exist a $k(x)$ such that $c= k(x)h(x)$. And also $< h(x) > \subset < f(x) > +< g(x) >$ because exist a linear combination of $ f(x), g(x) $ such that $h(x)= t(x)f(x)  +s(x)g(x) $ so if $c \in h(x)$ then exist $l(x)$ such that $c= l(x)t(x)f(x)+l(x)s(x)g(x)$ and so we have $$< h(x) > = < f(x) > +< g(x) >$$

Comment: This answer proves one characterisation of a $gcd$ with another, however, it does not explain why a gcd exists in the OP's situation, nor how to find it. In other words, I'm blowing my own horn but this answer only makes sense together with my comment.